# List in a RecycleView's adapter appears sometime, failed other time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, okhttp, butterknife, android-mvp

I ran into a quite evasive issue when developing an android app. The app is a client of a cryptocurrency RESTFul service. In its simplest form, it fetches the information of a range of virtual coins and display them in a list, presented using a RecycleView component.

The issue is that the list of coins sometime is displayed as expected, see below
[image]

other time, however it failed to do so, even my debugging line tells me the data has been fetched. In the latter case, the list will show up when I drag and pull down the screen (oh yeah I added the SwipeRefreshLayout to my Fragment class and implemented the necessaries).

[image]

The app was developed using MVP pattern, relevant code are as follows:

The interactor class acts as backend service that fetch JSON data via a RESTFul service, OKHttp lib and RxJava are used:

```
@Override
public Observable<List<Coin>> fetchCoins(){
    //TODO
    return Observable.fromCallable(this::getCoinList);
}

private List<Coin> getCoinList() throws IOException, JSONException {
    Request request = RequestGenerator.get(Api.BIT_COINS_LIST);
    String response = requestHandler.request(request);
    List<Coin> coinList = CoinListingParser.parse(response);
    return coinList;
}
```

The presenter class bridge the data fetched from interactor and the view class:

```
@Override
public void fetchCoins() {
    showLoading();
    fetchSubscription = coinListingInteractor.fetchCoins().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::onCoinFetchSuccess, this::onCoinFetchFailed);
}


    private void onCoinFetchSuccess(List<Coin> list)
{
    Log.d("CoinListing", "fetch succeeded");
    if (isViewAttached())
    {
        coinListView.showCoins(list);
        coinListView.loaded();
    }
}
```

Fragment class implements the coinListView class and implement the showCoins method that we saw in the presenter class so that the data and the GUI components are binded - ButterKnife is used for succinct and clear code:

```
public class CoinListingFragment extends Fragment implements CoinListingView,SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    @Inject
    CoinListingPresenter coinPresenter;

    @Bind(R.id.coin_listing)
    RecyclerView coinListRecycleView;

    @Bind(R.id.swipe_container)
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private List<Coin> coinList = new ArrayList<>(20);

    @Override
    public void showCoins(List<Coin> list) {
        this.coinList.clear();
        this.coinList.addAll(list);
        coinListRecycleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(()-> {coinPresenter.fetchCoins();});
    }
}
```

The accompanying RecycleView.Adapter class looks like:

```
public class CoinListingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CoinListingAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<Coin> coinList;
    private Context context;
    private CoinListingView view;
    public CoinListingAdapter(List<Coin> list, CoinListingView coinView)
    {
        this.coinList = list;
        view = coinView;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        context = parent.getContext();
        View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_coin_list_grid, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(rootView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(holder);
        holder.coin = coinList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(holder.coin.getFullName()+"("+holder.coin.getName()+")");
        Picasso.with(context).load(holder.coin.getImageUrl()).into(holder.img);
        holder.price.setText(holder.coin.getPrice());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return coinList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        @Bind(R.id.coin_name)
        public TextView name;
        @Bind(R.id.image_thumb)
        public ImageView img;
        @Bind(R.id.coin_price)
        public TextView price;

        public Coin coin;

        public ViewHolder(View root)
        {
            super(root);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, root);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple things I'm looking at that may be problems, but can't see. I'm not seeing where you're interacting with the adapter outside of `notifyDataSetChanged()`. You're adding to and clearing the `List<Coin>`, but not the adapter. I don't know what `coinListView.loaded()` does. I'm wondering if 1: You reinstantiated `coinList`, and 2: if there's a race clearing and updating RecyclerView.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Moving the List part to Adapter is a good suggestion. Loaded() is just to stop the spinning of the waiting icon when loading is settled down. I found, however, that I was barking at the wrong tree. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I was asking the wrong question. The issue was with the RESTFul webserivce not the client. The service provider restricts the access to their service. When requesting too frequently, a "Rate Limit exceeded" error is thrown and no data would be fetched.